# C++ Binary Tree Programming new Nodes leaving Scope issue

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am a java programmer teaching myself C++.

While writing a binary tree I found that my program did not "add" values to the tree.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class BinaryTree {

    struct Node {
    public:
        int val;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        Node::Node(int v) {
            val = v;
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
    };
public:
    BinaryTree() {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    int size = 0;
    int length();
    bool BinaryTree::add(int v);
    void printTree();
private:
    void printTree(Node* n); 
    Node* root;

};
bool BinaryTree::add(int v) {

    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node(v);
        ++size;
        return true;
    }
    Node* ref = root;
    cout << ref->val;
    while (ref != nullptr) {
        if (v < ref->val) {
            ref = ref->left;
        }
        else if (v > ref->val) {
            ref = ref->right;
        }
        else if (v == ref->val) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    Node *newNode = new Node(v);
    ref = newNode;
    ++size;
    return true;
}
void BinaryTree::printTree() {
    printTree(root);
}
void BinaryTree::printTree(Node* n) {
    if (n == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    printTree(n->left);
    cout << n->val << endl;
    printTree(n->right);
}
int BinaryTree::length() {
    return size;
}
void main(int i) {
    BinaryTree tree = BinaryTree();
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(3);
    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(7);
    tree.add(1);
    tree.add(0);
    tree.add(0);

    tree.printTree();
    cout << "binary tree sz is " << tree.length() << endl;
    while (true) {};
}
```

I have been unable to find the problem in regards to why the tree doesn't commit new Nodes except the root.

I used "new" in the code when writing (ref = new Node) etc in the adds method because this should prevent the new Node from being destroyed once it leaves the scope.

If anyone can enlighten me on this issue I will be greatly thankful.

Comment: *I am a java programmer teaching myself C++* -- This is not the correct signature for the `main` function:  `void main(int i)` -- You aren't going to learn C++ by guessing what is correct by using Java as a model.

Comment: Seems like the problem here is that you're not linking the `new Node(v)` with the `ref`. You need a `Node` constructor that takes a `Node*` and a `bool` saying whether it's left or right.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1551/) is a good binary tree example

Comment: The main issue here is in the add method.
Ref should eventually find a Node that has either the same value (and return false) or find a nullptr Node in which case it becomes a new Node.

This is typical of Java programming though I am unsure of why it does not work in C++. 

Yes I know C++ is vastly different and I shouldn't use Java as a template, but what in this specific example is wrong?

Comment: `bool BinaryTree::add(int v);` doesn't seem right in your class definition. `else if(v == ref->val)` should be just `else`..

Answer (score 2):

To add a node to the tree you have to link it to some existing node, as in

```
    existing_node->{left or right} = new_node;
```

Once `ref` becomes nullptr, you don't have a valid existing node anymore, and it is too late to do anything. Instead, traverse the tree as long as `ref->{left or right}` is valid:

```
    if (v < ref->val) {
        if (ref->left) {
            ref = ref->left;
        } else {
            ref->left = newNode;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // etc for v > ref->val
```